# How can I get the POST And GET data that is passed in my ASP.Net application URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, get

I'm trying to get this:

www.mytest.com/form?a=123&u=123123

How can I programatically C#, get the variables in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string a= Page.Request.QueryString["a"];
string u= Page.Request.QueryString["u"];
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work no matter if the request is POST or GET

```
string myData = Page.Request["a"]
```

If it's a POST request, the data won't go on the querystring, take this into account.

Comment: Also, Params["a"] etc. Params can be handy, albeit VERY confusing to some. I like it, my coworkers shudder. Go figure.